# why does beforeEach not run on the 2nd describe() statement in mocha?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, mocha.js

The first `beforeEach` clears out the User collection...which works fine for the first set of tests (the #save() describe)...but not for the 2nd describe("#find()").

```
describe('User', function(){
    beforeEach(function(done){
        //clear out db
        User.remove(done);
    });

    describe('#save()', function(){

        beforeEach(function(done){
            user = new User(fakeUser);
            done();
        });

        it('should have username property', function(done){
        });


        it('should not save if username is not present', function(done){
        });
    });

    describe('#find()', function(){
        beforeEach(function(done){
            user = new User(fakeUser);
            user.save(function(err, user){
                done();
            });
        });

        it('should find user by email', function(done){
        });

        it('should find user by username', function(done){
        });
    });
});
```

What does the very first `beforeEac`h refer to? I thought it runs for each child `describe`, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I needed to add `after` to drop the collection.